# How to assign case statement that has alias to variable using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

In my code below I'm trying to assign the results of a `CASE` statement to a variable. I got that working but my problem is that my `CASE` statement has an alias for the column name but I'm getting an "incorrect syntax near 'AS'".

I need to SUM my variables to get a GRAND TOTAL in that column as well. I am working with SQL Server 2014.

I could not find a solution and was hoping that someone can provide some direction / help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a1.SCHYEAR, a1.LocationName as LOCATIONNAME, a1.GRADE, 
    a1.[RACE/ETHNICITY], 
    @504Count = (CASE
                    WHEN a1.StudentPermID IN (SELECT DISTINCT t4.Permnum FROM #504 t4) 
                      THEN COUNT(a1.StudentPermID)
                 END),
    @Non504SPEDCount = (CASE
                           WHEN a1.STID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t1.STID FROM #speds t1) 
                             THEN COUNT(a1.STID)
                           WHEN a1.StudentPermID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t3.Permnum FROM #504 t3) 
                             THEN COUNT(a1.StudentPermID)
                        END),
    @SPEDCount = (CASE 
                     WHEN a1.STID IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.STID FROM #speds t2) 
                       THEN COUNT(a1.STID)
                  END),
    a1.STID, a1.StudentPermID as PERMNUM, @504Count as '504', 
    @Non504SPEDCount as 'Non-504/Non-SPED', @SPEDCount as 'SPED', 
    SUM(@504Count + @Non504SPEDCount + @SPEDCount) AS 'Grand Total'
FROM 
    #allStudents a1
GROUP BY 
    a1.SCHYEAR, a1.LocationName, a1.GRADE, a1.[RACE/ETHNICITY], a1.STID, 
    a1.StudentPermID
ORDER BY 
    a1.SCHYEAR, a1.LocationName, a1.GRADE, a1.[RACE/ETHNICITY], a1.STID, 
    a1.StudentPermID
```

Comment: have you tried putting `as <..>` outside parenthesis?

Comment: Give the alias name in square Brackets, not in the quotes. But in this case you won't need alias names.

Comment: your statement confuses me. a strange column name like `504` belongs in `[]`not `''` .  ` col IN (SELECT DISTINCT  ...) ` the distinct is useless. a select staement that assigns a value can't output any data.

Comment: You're correct A.  I just found that out as I got an error.

Answer (score 1):

As not required when you are assigning value to variable

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a1.SCHYEAR, a1.LocationName as LOCATIONNAME, a1.GRADE, a1.[RACE/ETHNICITY], 
    @504Count=(
    CASE
        WHEN a1.StudentPermID IN (SELECT DISTINCT t4.Permnum FROM #504 t4) THEN COUNT(a1.StudentPermID)
    END )AS '504',
    @Non504SPEDCount =(
    CASE
        WHEN a1.STID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t1.STID FROM #speds t1) THEN COUNT(a1.STID)
        WHEN a1.StudentPermID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t3.Permnum FROM #504 t3) THEN COUNT(a1.StudentPermID)
    END ) AS 'Non-504/Non-SPED',
    @SPEDCount=(
    CASE 
        WHEN a1.STID IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.STID FROM #speds t2) THEN COUNT(a1.STID)
    END ) AS 'SPED',
    a1.STID, a1.StudentPermID as PERMNUM, COUNT('504'), COUNT('Non-SPED'), COUNT('SPED'),
    SUM(@504Count + @Non504SPEDCount + @SPEDCount) AS 'Grand Total' 
    FROM #allStudents a1
    GROUP BY a1.SCHYEAR, a1.LocationName, a1.GRADE, a1.[RACE/ETHNICITY], a1.STID, a1.StudentPermID
    ORDER BY a1.SCHYEAR, a1.LocationName, a1.GRADE, a1.[RACE/ETHNICITY], a1.STID, a1.StudentPermID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a1.SCHYEAR, a1.LocationName as LOCATIONNAME, a1.GRADE, a1.[RACE/ETHNICITY], 
    @504Count=(
    CASE
        WHEN a1.StudentPermID IN (SELECT DISTINCT t4.Permnum FROM #504 t4) THEN COUNT(a1.StudentPermID)
    END),
    @Non504SPEDCount =(
    CASE
        WHEN a1.STID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t1.STID FROM #speds t1) THEN COUNT(a1.STID)
        WHEN a1.StudentPermID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t3.Permnum FROM #504 t3) THEN COUNT(a1.StudentPermID)
    END),
    @SPEDCount=(
    CASE 
        WHEN a1.STID IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.STID FROM #speds t2) THEN COUNT(a1.STID)
    END),
    a1.STID, a1.StudentPermID as PERMNUM, COUNT('504'), COUNT('Non-SPED'), COUNT('SPED'),
    SUM(@504Count + @Non504SPEDCount + @SPEDCount) AS 'Grand Total' 
    FROM #allStudents a1
    GROUP BY a1.SCHYEAR, a1.LocationName, a1.GRADE, a1.[RACE/ETHNICITY], a1.STID, a1.StudentPermID
    ORDER BY a1.SCHYEAR, a1.LocationName, a1.GRADE, a1.[RACE/ETHNICITY], a1.STID, a1.StudentPermID
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.  I think I finally got my code fixed with the ALIAS issue I had.  I modified my code above.

But now when I try to execute my code I get this error:

Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 122
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Line 122 is the SELECT DISTINCT statement in the first line of my code above.  Thanks.

Comment: At a time SQL select can perform a single function 'Retrieve Data' or 'Set value'. But you are try to do simultaneous function at a time. Just change it.

Comment: Thanks DineshDB.  However, I'm not sure how you mean to change it.  I'll keep trying...